# VB6: Minor memory management mystery

Tags: vb6, 32bit-64bit, ole

I can't quite wrap my head around what just happened in a VB6 program. This is on Win7-64 and Win10.

I wrote a Q & D proof of concept for loading and displaying 4K (3640x2160) images. Each image takes up 24MB of memory, so I "knew", based on the 2GB memory limit for 32-bit processes, that I could load at most ~80 images.

The system has 32GB of memory, but that's all not accessible to my program... right?

```
Const nPix As Long = 80

Dim Pix(1 To nPix) as stdPicture  ' an OLE construct
For k = 1 to nPix
   Pix(k) = LoadPicture("next in folder")
Next
```

No problem, takes a bit of time but works and uses the expected memory.

For grins I increased nPix to 100, just to see how it failed. But it didn't. Tried nPix = 200, then 300. Still kept going, by then eating up 8GB of system memory. And no problem at all with:

```
PictureBox.PaintPicture Pix(300)
```

What the heck is going on here? Whose memory am I using, and how?

Comment: Is that indeed stand-alone VB6 (as opposed to e.g. VBA that can be x64)? In the process manager, is all consumed memory attributed to the VB process? Does the result change it you `PaintPicture` all of them in a loop?

Comment: @GSerg - Yes, standalone native-code compiled VB6 app. Same happens in IDE. Process manager shows 8GB in use, with 1.8GB allocated to the VB6 app *and no other process claiming the rest*. I can PaintPicture random images from the array all day long, in less than 1ms each, with no changes shown in allocation.

Comment: Apparently it's an example of the fact that [virtual memory is not virtual address space](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040810-00/?p=38203). Windows maps as much memory as it can (e.g. `1.8GB`), the rest is mapped/unmapped on demand as you try to access different pictures. That wouldn't work if the `Pix` array had to store the picture bits themselves (and so all pictures would have to be mapped at the same time), but it only stores pointers of 4 bytes each, and the data is mapped on individual basis.

Comment: @GSerg - Sure, this is virtual memory (all Windows memory is) but VB6 doesn't understand an address space > 2GB, virtual or otherwise, and those 4 byte pointers (really 'handles' I guess) clearly can't point outside its 2GB allocation. So I suppose it's OLE that's handling this behind VB's back. No complaints, it's a wonderful thing, just quite unexpected (by me).

Comment: No 32-bit process can understand such addresses. The point is that virtual addressing involves multiple layers of address-resolving tables. The pointers in `Pix` point within the 2GB, but how these mapped-to addresses are later resolved is another matter. That is why "virtual memory is not virtual address space".

Comment: Please explain what exactly stdPicture is? Maybe there is something hidden going on.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor - stdPicture is an OLE construct, part of `stdole` as provided when you include a reference to `OLE Automation` in a VB project (which VB does by default for new projects). It's more or less equivalent to `iPictureDisp`. And there is certainly something hidden going on. OLE is performing the `LoadPicture` and passing VB6 a handle to the picture object.

Comment: @JimMack: thanks for description, my suspicion was that this object do something like compression on the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the images are loaded by operating system itself and only returns some kind of handle to VB6 process for manipulating...